# load text from .txt into praat info window

Tags: praat

I would like to read the information from a text file in the praat window.  I can "echo" text to the window with:

```
writeInfoLine: "Hello World"
appendInfoLine: "Goodbye"
```

But what I don't know how to do is to do the same thing if I have

```
"Hello World"
"Goodbye"
```

saved to a simple .txt file

I want to load the content of this file into the Praat Info window and save it to another .txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read plain text into a `Strings` object and then manipulate the strings depending on your needs.

```
Read Strings from raw text file: "text.txt"
numberOfStrings = Get number of strings

for stringNumber from 1 to numberOfStrings
     string$ = Get string: stringNumber
     appendInfoLine: string$
endfor
```

You can use `appenFileLine: "output.txt", string$` to write to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Other than for debugging, there are in general `0` reasons to use the Info window.

In this case, if what you want is to copy the contents from one file to another using Praat, you could use `readFile()` and `writeFile()`:

```
writeFile: target$, readFile$(source$)
```

If, on the other hand, what you want is to dump the text file to the Info window, you don't need to loop through the `Strings` object:

```
writeInfo: readFile$(source$)
```